# Ray tracing to a Point Cloud with a custom vertex shader in Three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl

How can you ray trace to a Point Cloud with a custom vertex shader in three.js.

This is my vertex shader

```
void main() {
  vUvP = vec2( position.x / (width*2.0), position.y / (height*2.0)+0.5 );
  colorP = vec2( position.x / (width*2.0)+0.5 , position.y / (height*2.0)  );
  vec4 pos = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
  depthVariance = 0.0;
  if ( (vUvP.x<0.0)|| (vUvP.x>0.5) || (vUvP.y<0.5) || (vUvP.y>0.0)) {
     vec2 smp = decodeDepth(vec2(position.x, position.y));
     float depth = smp.x;
     depthVariance = smp.y; 
     float z = -depth;
     pos = vec4(( position.x / width - 0.5 ) * z * (1000.0/focallength) * -1.0,( position.y / height - 0.5 ) * z * (1000.0/focallength),(- z + zOffset / 1000.0) * 2.0,1.0);
     vec2 maskP = vec2( position.x / (width*2.0), position.y / (height*2.0)  );
     vec4 maskColor = texture2D( map, maskP );
     maskVal = ( maskColor.r + maskColor.g + maskColor.b ) / 3.0 ;
  }
  gl_PointSize = pointSize;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * pos;
}
```

In the Points class, ray tracing is implemented as follows:

```
function testPoint( point, index ) {
    var rayPointDistanceSq = ray.distanceSqToPoint( point );
    if ( rayPointDistanceSq < localThresholdSq ) {
      var intersectPoint = ray.closestPointToPoint( point );
      intersectPoint.applyMatrix4( matrixWorld );
      var distance = raycaster.ray.origin.distanceTo( intersectPoint );
      if ( distance < raycaster.near || distance > raycaster.far ) return;
      intersects.push( {
          distance: distance,
          distanceToRay: Math.sqrt( rayPointDistanceSq ),
          point: intersectPoint.clone(),
          index: index,
          face: null,
          object: object
       } );
    }
 }

var vertices = geometry.vertices;
for ( var i = 0, l = vertices.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
       testPoint( vertices[ i ], i );
}
```

However, since I'm using a vertex shader, the geometry.vertices don't match up to the vertices on the screen which prevents the ray trace from working.

Can we get the points back from the vertex shader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't dive into what your vertex-shader actually does, and I assume there are good reasons for you to do it in the shader, so it's likely not feasible to redo the calculations in javascript when doing the ray-casting.

One approach could be to have some sort of estimate for where the points are, use those for a preselection and do some more involved calculation for the points that are closest to the ray.

If that won't work, your best bet would be to render a lookup-map of your scene, where color-values are the id of a point that is rendered at the coordinates (this is also referred to as GPU-picking, examples [here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu.html), [here](http://brianxu.github.io/GPUPicker/) and even some library [here](https://github.com/brianxu/GPUPicker) although that doesn't really do what you will need).

To do that, you need to render your scene twice: create a lookup-map in the first pass and render it regularly in the second pass. The lookup-map will store for every pixel which particle was rendered there.

To get that information you need to setup a `THREE.RenderTarget` (this might be downscaled to half the width/height for better performance) and a different material. The vertex-shader stays as it is, but the fragment-shader will just output a single, unique color-value for every particle (or anything that you can use to identify them). Then render the scene (or better: only the parts that should be raycast-targets) into the renderTarget:

```
var size = renderer.getSize();
var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
renderer.render(pickingScene, camera, renderTarget);
```

After rendering, you can obtain the content of this lookup-texture using the [`renderer.readRenderTargetPixels`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L2623)-method:

```
var pixelData = new Uint8Array(width * height * 4);
renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(renderTarget, 0, 0, width, height, pixelData);
```

(the layout of pixelData here is the same as for a regular canvas `imageData.data`)

Once you have that, the raycaster will only need to lookup a single coordinate, read and interpret the color-value as object-id and do something with it.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll just add for anyone attempting this in the future. In the vertex shader you can set a varying, which you can then use in the fragment shader where you would set the colours of the vertices